# NestJs Testing with CACHE_MANAGER injected

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs

I have some service in which I inject the CACHE_MANAGER in the constructor

```
import { CACHE_MANAGER, Inject, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Cache } from 'cache-manager';
...
export class ManagerService {
   constructor(@Inject(CACHE_MANAGER) private cacheManager: Cache) {}
   ...
}
```

That gives me an error when I test the modules the import those service

`Nest can't resolve dependencies of the ManagerService (?). Please make sure that the argument CACHE_MANAGER at index [0] is available in the Web3ManagerService context.`

I'm relatively new to NestJs so I really cannot figure out how to solve it

Answer (score 13):

I just had the same problem and resolved it this way:

*manager.service.spec.ts*

```
beforeEach(async () => {
  const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
    providers: [ManagerService, { provide: CACHE_MANAGER, useValue: {} }],
  }).compile();

  service = module.get<ManagerService>(ManagerService);
});
```

Answer (score 9):

To inject the cache manager provider under the `CACHE_MANAGER`, you need to import the nestjs module that creates this provider into the module that has the `ManagerService`

```
@Module({
  imports: [CacheModule.register()], // <<<<
  providers: [ManagerService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

like the docs shows https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/caching

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried with that but i get the same result

Comment: edit your question to show us the module in where you're registering the `ManagerService` provider

Comment: Just to add some context, as long as the service with the injection is passed to the module as provider it works. The problem seems to happen when i pass in the "imports" array any service with the injection

Comment: wait, are you passing services to the `imports` array? from the docs: `imports` is a list of _modules_

Comment: so if the service of the module needs dependencies in the constructor how to pass them?

Comment: you'll need to import the module that defines that dependency in your dependent module, not the service (if it was already registered in another module). The docs covers this topic pretty well

Comment: Use `CacheModule.register({ isGlobal: true })` for global registration. Try this if you're still getting an error.

Answer (score 3):

Set `isGlobal: true`:

```
CacheModule.register({
    url: process.env.REDIS_URL,
    db: 0,
    port: parseInt(process.env.REDIS_PORT),
    password: process.env.REDIS_PASSWORD,
    isGlobal: true, //<<<<<<<
})
```